# How to automatically determine features for machine learning?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, counting

I have to determine the number of elephant seals in an image. The original image is too big to be uploaded so there is a sample :
[Elephant seals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnTUW.jpg)
[image]

Classical image processing technics can not be used since animals and sand have slightly the same color. We would segment shadows or textures but not the seals. That's why I wanted to test machine learning.

The goal would be to determine manually some ROIs representing the seals and other for the sand in order to recognize the other animals in the image. The problem is that I don't know which feature I can use to describe seals and distinguish them from the sand.

Local histograms and its statistics (in particular mean and standard deviation) seem to be interesting but not enough. I thought about using image gradient but it did not lead to a good discrimination. Moreover, I think that a combination of several features must bu used but it's hard to tell which ones.

That's why I wonder if there was a way to determine automatically discriminative features to use them for the learning and predicting step of the machine learning algorithm.

In every tutos I found, descriptors were already defined.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: (Almost) everybody is using CNN nowadays, one of the reasons is that it works without knowing anything about the problem. The input is the pixels. No need to find features. But you'll have a hard time counting things using this type of machine learning. It will classify pixels into seal/not seal, but will not separate individual seals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, CNN seems to be a good approach to know whether a pixel belongs to a seal or to the sand. Combined with other technics, it would help to remove sand shapes. I need to go further and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have to determine the number of elephant seals in an image. .. any clue?*

### Well,
" *classical* " ML-Features ( *per-se* ) are not enough here :

this is a common situation for smart object recognition, which must provide a reasonable robustness, before any counting starts to have a sense.

As an example, CNN-methods deploy ( typically deep ) architectures of pre-processing with specialised kernels, that first help to decompose the 2D-scene into pre-cursors, that next may help the actual ML-based learner ( the fully connected "tail" section of the pipeline ) to start learning the object recognitions.

[image]

Without these ( deep or shallow ) convolutional layers and many there applied transcoding and pooling tricks, that re-rasterise the scene with non-linearly transformed co-local new, kernel-produced "visual"-features, pre-process these **auto**-synthetised-**features** for the ( yet ) deeper layers of the actual ML-learner.
[image]
Many papers published on this, so you are actually happy to have public sources to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I found a very clear tutorial [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/architecture-of-convolutional-neural-networks-simplified-demystified/). The global idea is quite intuitive but I need more practice. I will dive into it.

Comment: Yes I wanted to +1 your answer but I still miss some reputation point. I read that my +1 was taken into account in the database but not displayed here, so I'll try again when I'll have enough reputation points.